# PHP Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php

I got thie warnig:
PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference

and the code:

```
if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) &&
array_shift(explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])) == $gmt_mtime)
```

the second line code is the error one.

Comment: Get the value of `explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])` within a variable and pass it within your `array_shift`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to explode `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']` with ";"
and than you can use it in `array_shift` function.

```
<?
$exploded = explode(";",$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']);
if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) && array_shift($exploded) == $gmt_mtime))
?>
```

**Side Note:** I don't know its a typo error or not, well u need to add one ending ")" in if condition as well otherwise you will get the **PARSE ERROR**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to separate the `array_shift` and `explode` - something like this.

```
    $arr_gmt_mtime=explode( ';', $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] );
    if ( ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] ) && array_shift( $arr_gmt_mtime ) == $gmt_mtime )
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of `explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])` within a variable and pass it within your `array_shift` like as

```
$arr = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']);
if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) && array_shift($arr) == $gmt_mtime)
```